# How i can handle DB events with SockJS

Tags: node.js, mongodb, websocket, sockjs

guys! I have rest api application. That app work with MongoDB, write some model example.
How i can send some massage to all connection on SockJs server when i save some data in db?

Comment: The far easier way to do it might be to set up a redis server as well, as redis has tools for doing this kind of broadcasting

Comment: Thanks for comment, but application must be without redis.

Comment: MongoDB can't do this. You will have to implement this in your application server. The only workaround I could imagine which relies solely on MongoDB would be to have the clients constantly poll a collection which stores the latest events, but that would be really inefficient.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to do this using redis. You may refer to this article for guide

http://www.oditorium.com/ou/2014/02/implementing-a-pubsub-model-using-redis-nodejs-sockjs/

The way to do it is to subscribe all sockjs connection to a redis channel so you will have to create a redis subscriber client on every sockjs connection created but make sure that you unsubscribe and close the client once the sockjs connection is disconnected.